# category controller not found laravel with resource route

Tags: laravel

I have a resource route for category controller

// category controller routes

```
Route::resource('api/category', CategoryController::class);
```

categorycontrooller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function pruebas()
    {
        return "controlador de categoria";
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();

        return response()->json([
            'code' => 200,
            'status' =>'success',
            'categories' => $categories
        ]);
    }
}
```

php artisan route:list

```
  GET|HEAD        api/category ..... category.index › CategoryController@index
```

testing it with postman I got a 404 not found

```
BadMethodCallException: Method App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController::show does not exist. in file /var/www/html/api-rest-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 68
```

I dont know what is hapenning.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the Resource Controller seems to be incomplete.

You could either:

1. Create the resource controller. (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers)
2. Route resource only for index. (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes)

To follow step 1:

Delete/Rename the existing file and run:

```
php artisan make:controller CategoryController --resource
```

To follow step 2:

Edit your route to look like:

```
Route::resource('api/category', CategoryController::class)->only([
    'index'
]);
```

Comment: sachin I created again the category controller with the flag --resource and now in postman I dont get any errors and as well any data from the database

Comment: Your index method might be empty. Check the method: `public function index()`?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you are trying to access the single category and that route uses `show` method in the controller which is not defined. Also it's better to use plural name for your resource routes:

```
Route::resource('api/categories', CategoryController::class);
```